# How do I make a script in VScode so that when I press a key it will run and compile a Java program in an external terminal?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

How do I make a script in VScode so that when I press a key it will run and compile a Java program in an external terminal? I saw a tutorial of it in C# but I haven't seen a tutorial of it in Java. The tutorial used the `launch.json` file in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following setting in launch.json:

```
"console": "externalTerminal"
```

[image]

Comment: How do I create launch.json file?

Comment: Please refer to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_start-debugging

Comment: It's appreciate that if you can mark my answer, which will help more people who has the same question to achieve this solution.

Comment: I just found out how to do that.